# WooCommerce Product Category Widget Template Tag - drop down list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce plugin comes with a widget for product categories. I would like to display this widget outside of the sidebar using a template tag.

I can use this template tag `<?php the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories' ); ?>` but it displays the categories as an unordered list, I would like to display it as a drop down list.

The widget itself comes with options when you add it in the widget section, I cant figure out how to set these options (specifically the drop down list) in the template tag so it shows up correctly.

I also tried this tag `<?php woocommerce_product_dropdown_categories( 1,1,1,1 );?>` which displays the product categories as a drop down list but when you click on the category nothing happens (ie it doesn't take you to the category page you clicked on).

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, this is the tag I used:

`<?php the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', 'dropdown=1' ); ?>`

From the codex on [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) `<?php the_widget( $widget, $instance, $args ); ?>`